# How do I select the max date by each group with struct and array datatype in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data like below in Bigquery, which stored in array and struct

| ID | RECOMMEND.CATEGORY | RECOMMEND.RANK | RECOMMEND.DATE | RECOMMEND.HIT_GOODS.GOODS_CODE | RECOMMEND.HIT_GOODS.WEIGHT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | fruit | 1 | 2020-07-01 | apple | 100 |
|  |  |  |  | banana | 90 |
|  |  |  |  | orange | 80 |
|  | meat | 2 | 2020-06-01 | beef | 100 |
|  |  |  |  | pork | 90 |
|  |  |  |  | chicken | 80 |
|  | fruit | 3 | 2019-07-01 | apple | 100 |
|  |  |  |  | banana | 90 |
|  |  |  |  | orange | 80 |
| id2 | drinks | 1 | 2021-02-01 | cola | 100 |
|  |  |  |  | soda | 90 |
|  |  |  |  | water | 80 |
|  | drinks | 2 | 2020-12-01 | cola | 100 |
|  |  |  |  | soda | 90 |
|  |  |  |  | water | 80 |

How can I select the max date by category for each id and return as follow

| ID | RECOMMEND.CATEGORY | RECOMMEND.RANK | RECOMMEND.DATE | RECOMMEND.HIT_GOODS.GOODS_CODE | RECOMMEND.HIT_GOODS.WEIGHT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | fruit | 1 | 2020-07-01 | apple | 100 |
|  |  |  |  | banana | 90 |
|  |  |  |  | orange | 80 |
|  | meat | 2 | 2020-06-01 | beef | 100 |
|  |  |  |  | pork | 90 |
|  |  |  |  | chicken | 80 |
| id2 | drinks | 1 | 2021-02-01 | cola | 100 |
|  |  |  |  | soda | 90 |
|  |  |  |  | water | 80 |

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with following code, provide for those who also deal with similar problem.

```
SELECT ID, 
       ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(CATEGORY, RANK, DATE, HIT_GOODS) ORDER BY RANK) AS RECOMMEND
FROM (
    SELECT ID,
      RE.CATEGORY, RE.RANK, RE.DATE,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, RE.CATEGORY ORDER BY RE.DATE DESC) CAT_DUP_RANK,
      RE.HIT_GOODS
    FROM <table> df,
    df.RECOMMEND RE
    )
WHERE CAT_DUP_RANK = 1
GROUP BY ID
```